# Debugging missing audio

Tags: android, audio, driver

My Moto G5, model XT1676 using Android 8.1.0, has suddenly stopped its output via speakers (i.e. there's no sound from its speakers).

Volumes are all on max (media, call, alarm) and media players indicate that the sound files are playing, but nothing can be heard. Audio via headphones and bluetooth works as normal.

I have already done a "factory reset" via the settings menu (but not with a new ROM).

I have a few reasons to believe that this is a software problem (or a driver issue):

- there was no discernible event that could have damaged the speakers
- the audio output went directly to 0 without any intermediate state (no bad audio or crackling sound)
- the phone is rather new and shows no other signs of ageing
- vibrations were also not working, until after the factory reset

I assume it's rather impossible to guess the probable cause behind this from a distance, but maybe someone could give me a hint of how to narrow down the issue and how to check if my software/driver theory holds. Maybe I can avoid having to buy a new phone.

Every tip or hint will be highly appreciated!